# Headings not visible in mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, scrollreveal.js

The challenge encountered in the portfolio website pertains to the visibility of headings within the home section. Specifically, the ScrollReveal library seemed to face difficulties in appropriately revealing elements marked with the class 'heading'. The primary issue stemmed from the ScrollReveal configurations not effectively targeting and disclosing elements with this designated class.

To address this, a meticulous review of the JavaScript code governing the portfolio website was conducted. One crucial step involved ensuring that the headings within the home section were correctly assigned the class 'heading'. This is pivotal for ScrollReveal to identify and apply the intended reveal effects.

After integrating this modification, the website underwent testing to verify the effectiveness of the changes. It is crucial to confirm that the ScrollReveal library now accurately identifies elements with the class 'heading' and successfully executes the specified reveal animations.

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Initialize ScrollReveal for home-content
    ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content', {
        delay: 200,
        opacity: 0,
        distance: '80px',
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'ease',
        reset: true
    });

    let menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
    let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

    menuIcon.onclick = () => {
        menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
        navbar.classList.toggle('active');
    };

    let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
    let navLinks = document.querySelector('header nav');

    window.onscroll = () => {
        let top = window.scrollY;

        sections.forEach(sec => {
            let offset = sec.offsetTop - 150;
            let height = sec.offsetHeight;
            let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

            if (top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
                let activeLink = navLinks.querySelector(`a[href*=${id}]`);

                navLinks.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
                    link.classList.remove('active');
                });

                if (activeLink) {
                    activeLink.classList.add('active');
                }
            }
        });

        let header = document.querySelector('header');
        header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY > 100);
    };

    // Initialize ScrollReveal with options for desktop view
    if (window.innerWidth > 610) {
        ScrollReveal({
            distance: '80px',
            duration: 2000,
            delay: 200
        });

        ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content', { origin: 'top' });
        ScrollReveal().reveal('.heading', { origin: 'left' }); // Add this line for heading reveal
        ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-img, .services-container, .portfolio-box, .contact form', { origin: 'bottom' });
        ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content h1, .about-img', { origin: 'left' });
        ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content p, .about-content', { origin: 'right' });
    }

    // Initialize ScrollReveal with options
    const typed = new Typed('.multiple-text', {
        strings: ['Aspiring Developer', 'Gamer', 'Student', 'Athlete'],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        backSpeed: 100,
        backdelay: 1000,
        loop: true
    });

    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const fullName = document.getElementById("name");
    const email = document.getElementById("email");
    const phone = document.getElementById("phone");
    const subject = document.getElementById("subject");
    const mess = document.getElementById("message");

    function sendEmail() {
        const bodyMessage = `Full Name: ${fullName.value}<br> Email: ${email.value}<br> Phone Number: ${phone.value}<br> Message: ${mess.value}<br>`;

        Email.send({
            SecureToken: "e108a27e-9ccb-4823-bbc1-81e52d3d3f0a",
            To: "contactisindu@gmail.com",
            From: "contactisindu@gmail.com",
            Subject: subject.value,
            Body: bodyMessage
        }).then(
            message => {
                if (message == "OK") {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "Success!",
                        text: "Message sent successfully!",
                        icon: "success"
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    }

    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        sendEmail();
    });
});
```

Inspection of JavaScript Code:

Checked the JavaScript code responsible for initializing ScrollReveal.
Verified the configuration for elements with the class heading.
Identification of Class Mismatch:

Observed that there were no elements with the class heading in the HTML, which led to ScrollReveal being unable to locate and reveal these elements.
Modification of ScrollReveal Initialization:

Updated the ScrollReveal initialization to include the class heading for revealing.
Adjusted the initialization to specifically target the headings within the home section.
HTML Structure Verification:

Ensured that the home section headings in the HTML now have the class heading assigned to them

Answer (score 0):

Have You Write CSS for sticky Class You Have Used?